# Library to barcode scanner

Tags: android

I want to create application where I want to use barcode scanner. I Want to create my own layout and implement there this scanner. I find scandit, but I want to ask you if you know something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Jeff Lamarche's Cocoa Barcodes project for iPhone and iPad](https://github.com/netshade/Cocoa-Touch-Barcodes)

[Zxing's barcode image process library](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)

[Android barcode library](http://www.keepedge.com/products/android_barcode/)

[ISBN & QR Barcode Scanning Mobile App for Libraries](http://journal.code4lib.org/articles/5014)

http://zbar.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I use Zxing and can recommend it positively.